# Box plot with bands with standard deviation and range

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am new to R and ggplot2. Any help is much appreciated! I have here a data set, I am trying to graph

```
   weight band  mean_1     mean_2  SD_1       SD_2   min_1  min_2   max_1  max_2
    1            5         .           3        .    0.17       .    27   .
    2            6         .         3.7        .     1.1       .    23   .
    3            8         8         4.3        4.1     1   1.749    27   27
    4            8         9         3.3        6     2.3   1.402    13   42
```

In this set of data, I am trying to plot a bar graph of mean 1 and mean 2 side by side under the given weight_band (1-4) and applying error bars for min (1&2 respectively) and max (1&2 respectively). The "." notates that no data.

I have browsed through stackoverflow and other website, but haven't find the solution I am looking for.

the code I have is as follows:

```
sk1 <- read.csv(file="analysis.csv")    

library(reshape2)

sk2 <- melt(sk1,id.vars = "Weight_band")
c <- ggplot(sk2, aes(x = Weight_band, y = value, fill = variable))
c + geom_bar(stat = "identity",  position="dodge")
```

However, using this method, it does not limit the graph to only plotting the mean only. Is there a set of code to do so? Furthermore, is there a method to apply min and max as error bars to their respective mean? I thank everyone in advance. This would help me greatly in advancing my understanding of R's ggplot2 function

Answer (score 1):

This should get you close, we need to do a little more data cleaning and reshaping to make ggplot happy :)

```
library(reshape2)

df <- read.table(text = "weight_band  mean_1     mean_2  SD_1       SD_2   min_1  min_2   max_1  max_2
                 1            5         .           3        .    0.17       .    27   .
                 2            6         .         3.7        .     1.1       .    23   .
                 3            8         8         4.3        4.1     1   1.749    27   27
                 4            8         9         3.3        6     2.3   1.402    13   42", header = T)
sk2 <- melt(df,id.vars = "weight_band")

## Clean

sk2$group <- gsub(".*_(\\d)", "\\1", sk2$variable)
# new column used for color or fill aes and position dodging
sk2$variable <- gsub("_.*", "", sk2$variable)
# make these variables universal not group specific

## Reshape again

sk3 <- dcast(sk2, weight_band + group ~ variable)
# spread it back to kinda wide format
sk3 <- dplyr::mutate_if(sk3, is.character, as.numeric)
# convert every column to numeric if character now

# plot values seem a little wonky but the plot is coming together
ggplot(sk3, aes(x = as.factor(weight_band), y = mean, color = as.factor(group))) +
    geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = max, ymin = min), position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. this definitely helps alot!!

Comment: Just a quick question. I tried changing the cover of the weight band with  `code` scale_colour_manual("group",breaks=c(1,2),values=c("#0072B2", "#009E73")) `code`, but it didn't work. I am most likely coding it incorrectly.

Comment: try using `+ scale_colour_manual(values=c("#0072B2", "#009E73"))` instead